# EJJB Timer Transaction -XA Exception

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I am using EJB 3.0 timer.When my Timeout method gets invoked,I use JPA to insert a record in one of the table.I use JPA to persist the data.I defined the persist code in a Stateless Session Bean and invoked the local interface inside my timeout method.I get the following exception when the thread comes out of the timeout method:

```
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: JDBC driver does not support XA, hence cannot be a participant in two-phase commit.
   To force this participation, set the GlobalTransactionsProtocol attribute to LoggingLastResource (recommended) or EmulateTwoPhaseCommit for the Data Source
```

Our DB does not support XA transaction.We use WL 10.3.1.Here is the code which i do :

```
@EJB
private MyejbLocal myejbLocal 

@Timeout
public void callEjb(timer) {
    try {
     myejbLocal .store();

    } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
        e.getMessage();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getCause();
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation:

```
@Override  
public void Store() {
    try {
        Mytable mytable= new Mytable (new Date());
        persist(mytable);

    } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
        e.getMessage();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getCause();
    }

}
```

I don't call `flush()` method.

Please let me know if I have missed any?

Comment: I was able get this working by having the timer non-transactional and having my sesssionBean create a new Transaction.

Comment: That's one solution.  Of course, if your outer transaction rolls back, the Timer will still be created, so your timeout method will need to handle that scenario (if necessary).  It's probably best to figure out how to enable your datasource for XA.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. You need to keep your JPA entity operation in a separate session bean and it will work.

http://prasunejohn.blogspot.in/2014/02/understanding-ejb-timer-service-31.html